# Error while connecting to Oracle using JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ora-01034, ora-27101

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB using JDBC.

I have put `ojdbc.jar` in classpath.

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist IBM AIX RISC System/6000
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_27101_shared_memory_realm_does_not_exist.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database identified by your ORACLE_SID in the database url is not running. ORACLE_SID = case sensitive .....

I hope this helps,
Ronald.